# delete item from multidimensional ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` of this shape: `(148, 1, 2)`
With some coordinates:

```
[[[273 290]]

 [[271 292]]

 [[268 292]]

 [[267 293]]

 [[266 293]]

 [[265 294]]

 [[261 294]]

 [[261 295]]

 [[260 296]]

 [[258 296]]

 [[256 298]]

 [[254 298]]

 [[253 299]]

 [[250 299]]

 [[249 300]]

 [[247 300]]

 [[246 301]]

 [[244 301]]

 [[244 302]]

 [[242 304]]

 [[241 304]]

 [[240 305]]

 [[236 305]]

 [[234 307]]

 [[225 307]]

 [[225 308]]

 [[224 309]]

 [[198 309]]

 [[196 307]]

 [[192 307]]

 [[190 305]]

 [[171 305]]

 [[170 306]]

 [[166 306]]

 [[165 307]]

 [[164 307]]

 [[163 308]]

 [[161 308]]

 [[160 309]]

 [[166 309]]

 [[167 308]]

 [[168 308]]

 [[169 307]]

 [[180 307]]

 [[181 308]]

 [[189 308]]

 [[190 309]]

 [[189 310]]

 [[194 310]]

 [[196 312]]

 [[202 312]]

 [[203 313]]

 [[203 314]]

 [[204 313]]

 [[205 314]]

 [[224 314]]

 [[223 313]]

 [[224 312]]

 [[241 312]]

 [[242 313]]

 [[242 314]]

 [[243 314]]

 [[245 316]]

 [[245 319]]

 [[244 320]]

 [[244 322]]

 [[245 323]]

 [[245 324]]

 [[244 325]]

 [[244 326]]

 [[245 326]]

 [[246 325]]

 [[247 326]]

 [[252 326]]

 [[253 327]]

 [[253 328]]

 [[256 328]]

 [[257 329]]

 [[257 330]]

 [[261 330]]

 [[262 331]]

 [[262 332]]

 [[272 332]]

 [[273 333]]

 [[273 334]]

 [[281 334]]

 [[282 333]]

 [[286 333]]

 [[287 332]]

 [[298 332]]

 [[299 331]]

 [[306 331]]

 [[306 330]]

 [[307 329]]

 [[311 329]]

 [[313 327]]

 [[316 327]]

 [[318 325]]

 [[322 325]]

 [[323 324]]

 [[324 324]]

 [[325 323]]

 [[328 323]]

 [[328 322]]

 [[329 321]]

 [[330 321]]

 [[330 320]]

 [[333 317]]

 [[334 317]]

 [[334 316]]

 [[335 315]]

 [[337 315]]

 [[337 314]]

 [[338 313]]

 [[338 312]]

 [[339 311]]

 [[339 308]]

 [[338 307]]

 [[338 306]]

 [[336 304]]

 [[335 304]]

 [[334 303]]

 [[327 303]]

 [[326 302]]

 [[325 302]]

 [[324 303]]

 [[322 301]]

 [[320 301]]

 [[318 299]]

 [[316 299]]

 [[315 298]]

 [[315 297]]

 [[313 297]]

 [[312 296]]

 [[310 296]]

 [[309 295]]

 [[308 295]]

 [[307 296]]

 [[295 296]]

 [[294 297]]

 [[293 297]]

 [[290 294]]

 [[289 294]]

 [[288 293]]

 [[287 293]]

 [[285 291]]

 [[282 291]]

 [[281 290]]]
```

**I would delete some items (at some specific index)** in this array. I'm getting confused in how to do this, cause I really don't understand how to read this strange array.

ie: where are the commas of the array that separates its values?

Comment: Did you try `np.delete`?

Comment: yes, I already tried `new_a = np.delete( my_array, [1,2,3,4,5,6])` but this function destroy my array shape structure.

Comment: .. with `axis=0`?